# SQLite vs Core Data: saving large amounts of data

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, swift, core-data

I'm making a statistical analysis app which needs to store large amounts of data locally. To give you an idea of what I'm talking about, I've made this illustration (not exactly the right information, but very similar):

[image]

The app will keep track of several thousand destinations, with the destinations population, temperature, number of cars etc. These numbers will be represented in a graph so that you can look at the numbers "development" over time. This will go over a long period of time, in other words: thousand of dates for each data-type for each thousands of cities.

To achieve this I need to save large amounts of data, and it is preferred to be done locally (is that crazy?). I'm stuck between digging deep into the foundation of Core data, or using my already decent skills in SQLite.

If you suggest I should use SQLite, could you refer to how you would implement this into your app (some code perhaps?).

If you suggest I should use core data (mainly for performance), please show me how you would implement this type of data model with entities, attributes, relationships etc. I can imagine using dictionaries saved in the core data would be a good solution?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: FYI re: "digging deep into the foundation of Core data" Core data is super easy to use once you set it up.

Comment: @LyndseyScott I have "set it up" but I still don't understand for example relationships.

Comment: If you're familiar with SQLite, I see no reason to switch to Core Data. One of the reasons we use SQLite directly is that we can easily send the database to an Android device and read it there as well. I like FMDB as a simple Objective-C wrapper on top of SQLite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Core Data is an *object persistence model*-- and there's your answer really, because every object has a little overhead, so having thousands of objects in memory at one time is problematic. If you already know SQL then that's another plus.

(Discussion of overall merits of core data is outside the scope of this question. The "music" app pulls it off using core data with thousands of items, I think, but because it only needs to display a subset of items. Map Kit drops down to C, and quite handles itself impressively with tens of thousands of single-digit byte items, which you can see running instruments with a Map Kit app.)

I've used SQLite in iOS and it's not a problem, being C-based and Objective C being a strict superset of C. There are various "wrappers" but look at these carefully, in case they take you back to every-row-an-object. I didn't use one and found the SQLite C setup to be tricky but fine. EDIT: I used [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-tutorial-for-ios-making-our-app), which is dated now for the Objective C but a clear overview of how to integrate SQLite.

The only catch is the bundle/documents distinction in iOS will catch you if you ship with large amounts of data and want to save to that database: you can't modify files in the bundle, so you need to create or copy an SQL database to the documents folder 1 time, maybe on first app launch, to use it. Since you can't delete from the bundle, now you have your database twice. A problem inherent to the way iOS is set up.

Answer (score 9):

If you're going with SQLite with Swift - I *highly* recommend using [this](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift) project.  I am using it in my current project and it is absolutely fantastic and works perfectly (I'm not affliated in any way with the project or author).  You actually drag that project into your project and it becomes a subproject, then you just set it up as 1. target dependency, 2. framework to link with, 3. copy framework (build phases), and it just works. Then you can handle your database with brilliantly constructed Swift interfaces rather than ugly cumbersome libsqlite calls.

I have used it for modest amounts of data.  A few databases and multiple tables. Clean and intuitive. So far I haven't found a single bug of any kind.  And Stephen Celis, the author, was responsive when I asked a question about a feature that wasn't documented (but actually is present and works, it turns out).  It's a prodigious effort.

Its so clean and tightly integrated with Swift that, if I didn't know better, I'd think Apple itself added SQLite support to the Swift language.

https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift

Comment: One of my concerns is about sorting and query language. I'm working with Core Data now but it seems quite hard to build an query language, i want to have full text search, order by relevance, is it possible with SQLite? I'm using mySQL and is SQLite similar to it?

Comment: @TomSawyer - Sorry I didn't get back to you back in December last year, must have missed the notification. Yes SQLite has a lot of similarities to MySQL but lighter-duty obviously. But if you're familiar with the former you should have no problem at all ramping right up with SQLite.